# Why is the Laplacian of $|f(x+iy)|^2$ equal to $4|′()|^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

In a question about harmonic and holomorphic functions in complex analysis, I was trying to expand $|f(x+iy)|^2 = 0$.

I did this by considering $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ and applying the Laplacian operator on $u(z)^2+v(z)^2$ and then using Cauchy-Riemann equations to simplify.

However in the solutions it was directly given that $ \Delta |f(x+iy)|^2 = 4|′()|^2$. I am not sure how this was given directly as there were no other steps.

Why is this step true?

Comment: As you go deeper and deeper in Math, things that can be verified in one or two lines are usually taken for granted as trivial and no steps are shown, as the author expects the reader to be able to fill the steps on their own.

Comment: If $\vert f(x + iy) \vert^2 = 0$, what is there to expand?

Comment: I mean expanding $ |f(x+iy)|^2 $ in order to show that $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y = 0$

Comment: The original question was to show that $f(z)$ must be constant given that $ |f(x+iy)|^2 $ harmonic and $f$ is holomorphic

Comment: Write $\lvert f(z)\rvert^2 = f(z)\cdot \overline{f(z)}$ and use $\Delta = 4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\overline{z}}$ if the Wirtinger derivatives were already introduced.

Comment: We haven't covered Wirtinger derivatives yet so I'm trying to see how it can be done without it.